# Mongoose delete an item in an array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i am a beginner in mongoose and i am trying to delete an element in array but i am facing troubles to do it

my schema is like this

```
    name : {
        type: String,
        trim : true
    },
    pictures: {
        type : Array,
        required : false
    },
```

and in my database it looks like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5eb67e7c74b35b205362b7f4"),
    "title" : "john doe",
    "pictures" : [ 
        "img1.jpg", 
        "img2.png", 
        "img3.jpg", 
        "img4.jpg", 
        "img5.jpg"
    ]
}
```

how can i delete an item in the array of pictures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [$pull](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/) operator:

```
await Model.updateOne({"_id" : ObjectId("5eb67e7c74b35b205362b7f4")}, {$pull: { "pictures": "img1.jpg"}});
```

Comment: it does not work but as you have showed me the way, i am now trying to make it work

Comment: i just replaced the objectId by plain id and now it works!